# Replace missing participant and data in R

Tags: r

I conducted a pretest and a post test but some students did not attend the post test. How do I replace them and replace their scores with post test mean. For example:

| Test | Student_ID | Scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pretest | 001 | 70 |
| Pretest | 002* | 65 |
| Pretest | 003 | 75 |
| Pretest | 004 | 60 |
| Pretest | 005* | 60 |
| Pretest | 006 | 67 |
| Posttest | 001 | 80 |
| Posttest | 003 | 76 |
| Posttest | 004 | 55 |
| Posttest | 006 | 79 |

Students **002** and **005** did not attend the post test. How do I include them and use the mean of post test as their score in R?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete` to help fill in the missing values. For example

```
tidyr::complete(dd, Test, Student_ID, 
  fill=list(Scores=mean(dd[dd$Test=="Posttest","Scores"])))
```

Returns

```
   Test     Student_ID Scores
   <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Posttest 001          80  
 2 Posttest 002          72.5
 3 Posttest 003          76  
 4 Posttest 004          55  
 5 Posttest 005          72.5
 6 Posttest 006          79  
 7 Pretest  001          70  
 8 Pretest  002          65  
 9 Pretest  003          75  
10 Pretest  004          60  
11 Pretest  005          60  
12 Pretest  006          67
```

Tested with

```
dd <- data.frame(
  Test = c("Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Posttest", "Posttest", "Posttest", "Posttest"), 
  Student_ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "001", "003", "004", "006"), 
  Scores = c(70, 65, 75, 60, 60, 67, 80, 76, 55, 79)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two dplyr methods:

1. pivot, fill, unpivot:

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)
   quux %>%
     pivot_wider(id_cols = Student_ID, names_from = Test, values_from = Scores) %>%
     mutate(across(-Student_ID, ~ replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
     pivot_longer(-Student_ID, names_to = "Test", values_to = "Scores")
   # # A tibble: 12 × 3
   #    Student_ID Test     Scores
   #         <int> <chr>     <dbl>
   #  1          1 Pretest    70  
   #  2          1 Posttest   80  
   #  3          2 Pretest    65  
   #  4          2 Posttest   72.5
   #  5          3 Pretest    75  
   #  6          3 Posttest   76  
   #  7          4 Pretest    60  
   #  8          4 Posttest   55  
   #  9          5 Pretest    60  
   # 10          5 Posttest   72.5
   # 11          6 Pretest    67  
   # 12          6 Posttest   79
   ```
2. Summarize, reframe, rejoin

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   quux %>%
     group_by(Student_ID) %>%
     filter(!all(averages$Test %in% Test)) %>%
     reframe(Test = setdiff(averages$Test, Test)) %>%
     left_join(averages, by = "Test") %>%
     bind_rows(quux)
   # # A tibble: 12 × 3
   #    Student_ID Test     Scores
   #         <int> <chr>     <dbl>
   #  1          2 Posttest   72.5
   #  2          5 Posttest   72.5
   #  3          1 Pretest    70  
   #  4          2 Pretest    65  
   #  5          3 Pretest    75  
   #  6          4 Pretest    60  
   #  7          5 Pretest    60  
   #  8          6 Pretest    67  
   #  9          1 Posttest   80  
   # 10          3 Posttest   76  
   # 11          4 Posttest   55  
   # 12          6 Posttest   79
   ```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Test = c("Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Pretest", "Posttest", "Posttest", "Posttest", "Posttest"), Student_ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L), Scores = c(70L, 65L, 75L, 60L, 60L, 67L, 80L, 76L, 55L, 79L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```